# Install not working on Windows 7

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, advanced-installer

I have an install that is made in Advanced Installer that works fine in Windows 8 & 10, but fails on Windows 7. Does a Windows 7-client have any requirements for connecting to a SQL Server (2012, on a different machine), that a Windows 8 or 10 machine does not have? Some drivers that does not exist on a clean Windows 7? The application in a Entity Framework-app and uses Framework 4.6.1 if that matters...

[Edit] Based on all the comments below I refrase my question to this: For a Clean, fully updated, Windows 7 to connect to a remote SQL Server (2008+), is there any other requirements/drivers that is needed to be installed other than .Net framework 4.6.1? For Windows 8 & 10 apparently there are no such requirements...

Comment: What error messages, if any do you receive on install failure?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that, no error during install, just a connection failure. And I should also have said SQL Server 2008+...

Comment: Ping works, firewall (port 1433) is opened...

Comment: Should FW 4.6.1 be enough for a clean Windows 7 client to connect to a remote SQL server?

Comment: Activate all connection protocols/types in the SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: I have activated tcp/ip, which works for  win 8 &  10, should be enough?

Comment: can the Win 7 machine connects to the SQL server 2012 using SSMS ?

Comment: I don't have SSMS on the W7 machine,  it is completely clean (but fully updated)  except for my program and FW 4.6.1.

Comment: It sounds like an application problem, not an installation problem if the installer is completing fine.  Does the connection error give you a stack trace in its logs?  Can you attach a debugger and trace it?

Comment: As I said in an earlier comment,  no installation error,  just failure to connect to the SQL server after the installation is done. So my question really is,  should FW 4.6.1 be enough on clean fully updated windows 7 machine to connect to a SQL server.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was partly the firewall, partly my network and partly my code. There are no special drivers etc needed to make a EF-application work in Windows 7. Once network, firewall etc was configured correctly, my application worked.